# Cross-compiled shared library won't link to libstdc++.so

Tags: python, c++, arm, shared-libraries

I'm trying to cross-compile my python c module for ARM (beaglebone-black to be specific). Everything seems to be okay but I can't get it to actually import correctly to what I'd assume is a linker run-time issue.

```
root@beaglebone:~# python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 14:38:51)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mypackage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mypackage.cpython-34m.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

root@beaglebone:~# ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mypackage.cpython-34m.so
        libstdc++.so.6 => not found
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6e88000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6 (0xb6d42000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6ef9000)

root@beaglebone:~# ls -l /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian admin    244 Nov 27 12:19 mypackage.egg-info
-rwxr-xr-x 1 debian admin 698298 Nov 27 12:19 mypackage.cpython-34m.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root   root  641216 Nov 27 12:29 libstdc++.so.6

root@beaglebone:~# ldconfig -p |grep libstd*
        libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6

root@beaglebone:~# file /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mypackage.cpython-34m.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mypackage.cpython-34m.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x9a03edac27af0002b195cc47ddc5396f80cb1366, not stripped

root@beaglebone:~# file /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/libstdc++.so.6: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x8aed4dbc737c88ee5428052996d7657298dd0952, stripped
```

Edited to answer question below:

```
root@beaglebone:~# readelf -A /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mypackage.cpython-34m.so
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "5T"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v5T
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int

root@beaglebone:~# readelf -A /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed

root@beaglebone:~# readelf -A /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "4T"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v4T
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
```

Comment: Have you tried: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/` ?

Comment: Yes, I get the same results.

Comment: All your libraries are hardfp? Could you check `readelf -A  /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mypackage.cpython-34m.so | grep "Tag_ABI_HardFP_use\|Tag_ABI_VFP_args"`?
`

Comment: I didn't get anything from the grep so I appended it above. I noticed libstdc++.so is different and in a different directory from the ones actually linking. Looks like this might be my issue?

Comment: I just realized there is soft float vs hard float and not really sure the difference between the two. I'm somewhat confused on why Debian's package manager would install libc as soft float and libstdc++ as a hard float. My compiler flags for the python package are `-mfloat-abi=softfp` as recommended by TI for the processor type.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue, I statically compiled libstdc++ into my library and its still giving the same python error. `LD_DEBUG=all` shows `file=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mypackage.cpython-34m.so [0];  dynamically loaded by python3 [0]` so I'm not sure whats going on here...

Comment: Could you please try to compile your python package with `-mfloat-abi=hard` and link everything dynamically?

Comment: That didn't work but changing from `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7` to `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.7` (g++ also) worked! Care to explain why that matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system appears to be **hard floating point**. The difference between hardfp and softfp is well summarized [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html).

```
-mfloat-abi=name
    Specifies which floating-point ABI to use. Permissible values are: ‘soft’, ‘softfp’
    and ‘hard’.

    Specifying ‘soft’ causes GCC to generate output containing library calls for 
    floating-point operations. ‘softfp’ allows the generation of code using hardware
    floating-point instructions, but still uses the soft-float calling conventions.
   ‘hard’ allows generation of floating-point instructions and uses FPU-specific
    calling conventions.

    The default depends on the specific target configuration. Note that the hard-float
    and soft-float ABIs are not link-compatible; you must compile your entire program
    with the same ABI, and link with a compatible set of libraries.
```

The last paragraph states that normally hardfp and softfp are not link compatible. When you execute your python interpreter (hard floating point), the dynamic linker tries to load `mypackage.cpython-34m.so`, a soft float shared object and fails.

When you execute ldd:

`ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mypackage.cpython-34m.so`

on the softfp shared object, the outcome is the following:

```
libstdc++.so.6 => not found
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6e88000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6 (0xb6d42000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6ef9000)
```

The `libstdc++.so.6` visible in the linker include paths (as shown by ldconfig) is `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6`, which is hard float and therefore incompatible. If `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/libstdc++.so.6` is soft float (I can't tell from your attempts), I would still expect the following export to fix that problem loading `libstdc++.so.6`.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
```

`/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6` is soft float instead, and it is loaded correctly. Why there's a soft float libc on your hard float system honestly I could not tell.

Anyway, to fix the initial problem with the python interpreter you need a hard float `mypackage.cpython-34m.so` and you need to be able to solve the dependencies with libraries compiled with the same ABI.

As you have already seen, by using the hard float version of `gcc/g++` (`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.7`) you managed to fix the runtime linking problem. Again I am not completely sure why simply using `-mfloat-abi=hard` didn't work. It should have produced a hard float binary and that should have been enough.